# C# How to replace system tray clock

Tags: c#, windows, windows-xp

How do I replace the standard system tray clock in the taskbar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an example here in C++: [C++ Open Source Project](http://wincalendartime.sourceforge.net/index.html)

I hope you are able to find something in C# as well.

Comment: DLL-injecting Explorer and dynamically subclassing the clock window?  What a magnificent kludge!